# Help with MySQL - Cannot start, restart, or load MySQL

Tags: mysql, shutdown, reboot, phpmyadmin, drupal

I'm honestly not 100% sure if this is the right place to ask but I figured someone might be able to at least point in the right direction, since I'm completely lost for answers and have no idea where to begin. I apologize in advance if I'm in the wrong place.

I'm working with a couple Drupal websites, Linux server, and as I was performing updates, coincidentally (...or not), the server went down, couldn't access Cpanel or WHM. When I could, all MySQL is down and I can't get them to restart.

I've searched a ton of pages on here (among other forums) for steps on how to shut down, restart, start, etc mySQL with no luck. The terminal just keep saying, "failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded". I can't even access phpMyAdmin in CPanel.

My biggest clue so far is that MySQL may have shut down abnormally or something along those lines, but I have no idea how to fix the bug, clean it, or where to begin.

Can anyone point in the right direction?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there anything useful in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`?

Comment: Thanks, Jos. I'm actually not sure how to access that or view that. Can you give me some lead?

Comment: Are you able to SSH into your server? There won’t be any graphical UIs from this point on … 

Comment: I have access to terminal. But Im unfamiliar with SSH. I tried reinstalling mySQL 5.7 (it claimed its useful for previously failed upgrades or partially incomplete). It didnt work and it said, "MySQL service failed to start. Contact system administrator if the service does not automatically recover". What can i try next?

Comment: Did your server provider give you SSH access to the server? If they did, you should be able to login from any system with a SSH client (like `putty` or `openssh-client`) using the credentials given. Then the basic command is `more /var/log/mysql/error.log`. If you don't have SSH access, there is little you can do apart from asking them what goes wrong.

Comment: I have access to a SSH Keys page in Cpanel, but I'm not skilled with working with SSH. So I have been unable to log in with putty. (I just get the "remote side unexpectedly closed network connection" error) I apologize for my slowness - this is all new to me and not my field. I'm trying to figure it out myself because no one else will or can help.

Comment: okay, I was able to get into SSH, I tried /var/log/mysql/error.log but I get "no such file or directory". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Update: after lots of asking around, my IT friend managed to help me fix the MySQL issue. It was some bugs that was caused from server crashing while an update was being performed. But the issue also caused databases to be corrupt, and even worse, the web host is having bandwidth issues and won't allow me to upload anything. What a headache! Thanks for your tips, guys.